# Bring me vs Take me

Tags: bring-take

I'm having a problem with a the use of *Bring* vs *Take*.  I know, more or less, the difference between *bring* and *take* but in this case the "thing" that has to be moved from here to a different place is ME, so it makes me a bit confused.

We are talking about some rails (train tracks) and I'm wondering the following:

> "Will they *[the rails]* bring me there?" (a known place)

or should I write:

> "Will they take me there?"

Comment: Either is acceptable, but not really colloquial. Unless waxing lyrical, you'd rephrase (Does this track lead to ..., etc).

Comment: I forgot to mention this line is part of a lyrics (a song).

Comment: On average, you're much more likely to ***Bring** something **here***, or ***Take** something **there***, rather than the other way around.

Comment: ... Yes, but as nohat says in the previous thread, the emphasis can be transferred to the (future) arrival by using 'bring' in the transferred sense. Thus 'Shortly after we saw the first American land, a pilot came on board and we trust that he will bring us safely to Baltimore.' [[P Thompson](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=4oYrFWIf0-IC&pg=PA5&lpg=PA5&dq=%22will+bring+us+safely+to%22+-heavenly+-God&source=bl&ots=qQ_IkrIwMz&sig=NbIoezm0VLHz2MJO_Kd89LUIb2g&hl=en&sa=X&ei=gMCjVYLZBKrW7AaTyYOICQ&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22will%20bring%20us%20safely%20to%22%20-heavenly%20-God&f=false)]

Comment: @ Edwin Ashworth Thanks Edwin, I've read the post you are referring to and seems that in my case Bring could be ok,,, if I understood it right. The emphasis in my case is on the "future destination place" he'll be. To make a long story short, this is the place the speaker hopes would be the right place to have a fresh new start, a new life.So it seems similar to "he will bring us safely to Baltimora". Is it right?

Comment: _Bring_ is generally the causative of _come_ and _take_ is the causative of _go_, so most or all of the constructions and idioms with _come_ and _go_ will work with _bring_ and _take_, respectively: _come/bring to an end, go/take to the cleaners,_ etc. As for ***me***, any situation where _go_ is ok will license _take_, and _come_ will license _bring_. But often either one can be used: _I'm going/coming to the party tonight; I'm taking/brining Susie to the party tonight._ A great deal depends on who the speaker is talking to, where both parties are located, and whether both will attend.

Comment: For more on coming and going and bringing and taking, consult Fillmore's [_Deixis Lectures_](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Deixis.html), particularly #1, ["May We Come In?"](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/1-MayWeComeIn.pdf) and #5, [Coming and Going](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/5-ComingAndGoing.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

In general the distinction between "bring" and "take" is determined by the **point of view of the speaker**.

***These rails will take me home.***   I would say these words at a railway station. I envisage rail tracks extending into the distance and my home is a small dot at the end of them.

***These rails will bring me home.***   When I say these words, I am physically located at the railway station but my mental picture is of me at the end of the journey having already arrived.

Comment: thanks. Your option n.2 is very much what I had in my mind when I wrote that line. So "bring" seems to be acceptable...